# jQuery UI change styling of dragged element

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I would like to change the color of a list item that is draggable once I drag it.

Thanks for your help.

```
$("#DragWordList li").draggable({helper: 'clone'});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to simply style the CSS class `ui-draggable-dragging`

e.g

```
.ui-draggable-dragging{
   border:1px dashed red;
   background:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class to the dragged cloned element in the drag event function like:

```
 $("#DragWordList li").draggable({
     helper: "clone",
     drag: function(ev,ui){
         ui.helper.addClass('red');
     }
 });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/AFkRL/

Comment: That is actually very simple and useful. Thanks.

Comment: @marwane probably you have preferred the other :-)